# The Difference between os.system and subprocess calls

Tags: python, subprocess

I have created a program that creates a web architecture in a local server then loads the necessary browser to display the html and php pages on localhost.

The `os.system` call kills the python process but doesn't kill the other processes -- for example, `httpd.exe` and `mysqld.exe`

The `subprocess` call kills the `httpd.exe` and `mysqld.exe` programs but continues to run the python code, and no code executes after the `subprocess` call.

How would i go about killing or hiding all necessary processes after the python code is executed?

Here is my code.

```
os.makedirs(dr + x + '/admin' + '/css')
dobj = open(dr + x + '/admin' + '/css' + '/style.css', 'w')
dobj.close()
del dobj
os.makedirs(dr + x + '/admin' + '/js')
os.makedirs(dr + x + '/admin' + '/img')
################################################################################
## THE OS SYSTEM CALLS CLOSE THE APP BUT OPEN THE PROCESSES
## AND THE SUBPROCESS CALLS CLOSE BOTH PROCESSES AND LEAVES THE APP OPEN
## CANT WIN!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
os.makedirs(dr + x + '/admin' + '/conf')
#os.system(r'C:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe')
#os.system(r'C:\\xampp\\mysql\\bin\\mysqld.exe')
subprocess.Popen(['C:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe'], shell=True, creationflags=subprocess.SW_HIDE)
subprocess.Popen(['C:\\xampp\\mysql\\bin\\mysqld.exe'], shell=True, creationflags=subprocess.SW_HIDE)
webbrowser.open('localhost/' + x)
sys.exit()
################################################################################


else:
    backmaybe = raw_input('Already Exists... Try Again? (Y/N) ')
if backmaybe == 'y':
    start()
else:
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: what is the desired running status of httpd, mysqld after `sys.exit()`?

Comment: if you want httpd, mysqld to keep running after your script exited; you could use [DETACHED_PROCESS | CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13256908/4279) flag. btw, you don't need `shell=True`.

Comment: the running status of httpd and mysqld should run stealthly, ive made this very user friendly, dont need any excess windows.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian How would i implement this? i am still in the early stages, but thankyou very much!

Comment: please, do [a minimal research yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[python]+[windows]+subprocess+hide+console&submit=search), see [ask].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between `os.system` and `subprocess.Popen` is that Popen actually opens a [pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29), and `os.system` starts a [subshell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_%28computing%29), much like `subprocess.call`. Windows only half-supports some pipe/shell features of what *nix operating systems will, but the difference should still fundamentally be the same. A subshell doesn't let you communicate with the standard input and output of another process like a pipe does.

What you probably want is to use subprocess like you are, but then call the kill() method ([from the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)) on the pipe object before your application terminates. That will let you decide when you want the process terminated. You might need to satisfy whatever i/o the process wants to do by calling `pipe.communicate()` and closing the pipe's file handles.