# os.system not working, but typing the same thing into the command prompt works

Tags: python, command-prompt, os.system, abaqus

I am trying to run python abaqus through the command prompt using

```
os.system('abaqus CAE noGUI=ODBMechens')
```

It doesn't seem to run anything, but if I go to the command prompt myself and type in

```
abaqus CAE noGUI=ODBMechens
```

it works. I am using python 2.7 on Windows 10.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *it doesn't seem to run?*

Comment: You **really** shouldn't use `os.system`. Use `subprocess` instead.

Comment: Are there any non-Ascii characters in the working one? The program is in the current directory so you could open the python shell and do `[(name, name.lower().=='abaqus.exe') for name in os.listdir('.')]`. Is the command there? Does it say True?

Comment: That last comment from tdelaney was a little too complicated for me. Do I just copy/paste what you wrote into the console window (I'm using Spyder)? I switched to subprocess as suggested (still not working as shown in comments below).

Comment: Stephen - When it runs it takes a while and then generates another file. This "runs" super quickly and doesn't generate the file.

Comment: do `which abaqus` at your command prompt to get the full path and use that full path in your system call. ( on windows do `where abaqus` )

Comment: That ended up being the problem. I still don't understand why it couldn't find abaqus when the command prompt could, but putting in the full path made it work. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I had a similar issue. After a fair amount of digging, I think the issue is that the PATH for my python install is done through Anaconda (this is how I got Spyder) so I have a different path this vs CMD. I fixed this by adding the full Abaqus location to the command. ```subprocess.call(r'C:\SIMULIA\Commands\abaqus job=Job-1 ask_delete=OFF interactive', shell=True)```

Answer (score 6):

try using the subprocess module (it's newer) instead:
for example,

```
subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"])
```

and in your example, it would be:

```
subprocess.call('abaqus CAE noGUI=ODBMechens')
```

More info on the difference between subprocess module and using os.system call:

[The Difference between os.system and subprocess calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13334634/the-difference-between-os-system-and-subprocess-calls)

Comment: I replaced my command with the second one that you have there, but it gives the following error:
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
What directory does it use to look for the files? At the command prompt I run it out of a folder on my H drive which is where the python file is.

Comment: I just checked "print os.getcwd()" and it has the same folder that I am using in the command prompt. Does the file need to be where python is installed?

Comment: No, it doesn't need to be where you installed python. but, maybe try going inside that folder and then running that python command. Try to replicate the exact environment within python as you would in the command prompt.

Comment: In the command window the following runs:
H:\NoSpaces>abaqus CAE noGUI=ODBMechens
The python file that I am running is H:\NoSpaces\RunINPfile.py
I should note that abaqus is not in that folder (it is a separate executable, but it runs fine from the command prompt)

Comment: so you're running that file which has the above python commands?

Comment: Yeah, it is currently:
import subprocess
subprocess.call('abaqus CAE noGUI=ODBMechens')

Comment: WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: are you sure you named the file correctly? and running it through python via: ```python name_of_file``` or ```python ./name_of_python_file```

Comment: I was just running it through Spyder (F5 button) but I ran it through the command prompt and got the same error "H:\NoSpaces>python RunINPfile.py"

Comment: if you type ```ls``` is that the exact name of the file (including upper and lower case characters)?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. I tried typing ls into the command prompt and it gave errors. I put it into the python console window and it showed everything in the folder (including ODBMechens.py).

Comment: I then made sure I had things typed correctly buy coping the command (that works) out of the command prompt and pasting it into the python file but that still didn't work.

Comment: After some investigation I believe it is having problems finding abaqus as when change it to "subprocess.call('abaqus')" it gives the same error. However, when I type "abaqus" into the command prompt it starts asking questions about Identifiers and Input Files rather than giving an error. I just want a command that takes exactly what I give it and runs it at the command prompt.

Comment: how are you starting python?

Comment: I ended up fixing it by adding the full path for abaqus. If you still care, I was running abaqus by loading the file into spyder and running it through there. I believe that I tried running it through the command prompt once too, but I don't remember the state of the code at that time. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @MarkGordon yup, np. I should of recommended trying the full path! It's a great first start

Answer (score 0):

You should add before your code

```
import os
import subprocess
try:
    os.environ.pop('PYTHONIOENCODING')
except KeyError:
    pass
```

And then:

```
cmd = subprocess.Popen('abaqus CAE noGUI=ODBMechens',cwd=jobPath, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                   stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()[0]
```

Variable cmd contains your output. I found that this way it works.