# python subprocess call Abaqus failed, only Matlab showed up unexpectedly

Tags: python, abaqus

I'm calling a command line to run Abaqus from python interpreter. However, no Abaqus engine stats in this process. Only Matlab program is opening, dont know why. Does this command interact with my Matlab? Anyone could indicate anything wrong with my subprocess call? Thx

```
import subprocess
process=subprocess.call('abaqus', 'cae', 'script=C:\Users\Desktop\modelAExample.py')
```

If I run the following command from cmd directly, it will work

```
abaqus cae script=modelAExample.py
```

Comment: Well, for one thing, there sure are a lot of unescaped backslashes in that pathname...

Comment: all thos args should be a single list, like : `subprocess.call(['abaqus', 'cae', 'script=C:\\Users\\Desktop\\modelAExample.py'])`  (note added square brackets)

Comment: @agentp I tried this. But everytime I run this. Nothing happens only with the Matlab opened unexpected.

Comment: try using the full path for abaqus. see here http://stackoverflow.com/q/43037012/1004168.   Do you want the abaqus GUI to open? If not use "noGUI=" instead of "script="

Answer (score 0):

I was going to write a comment, but it wouldn't format this properly. It could be that your script is exiting and not waiting on the process.

Try this:

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
import os

path = os.path.join("c:", "Users", "Desktop", "modelAExample.py")

if os.path.exists(path):
    proc = Popen(['abaqus', 'cae', 'script={}'.format(path)], stdout=PIPE)
    proc.communicate()

else: 
    print("Bad path")
```

Also, are you specifying the correct path to `modelAExample.py`? I don't see you specifying a username which usually follows `C:\Users\`

Comment: Yes, I just omitted the user name when typing this question. The code prints out Bad Path! However, the path is there exactly.

Comment: i think you need a slash in there `join("c:/",..`

Comment: @agentp According to this rated SO comment, you don't need the slash: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7767925/1703772. @rifle123 It looks like your path is incorrect. One way to verify your issue is by running `abaqus cae` and comparing the result with what you are seeing while specifying the `script` attribute. If the window opens in both modes, it's highly likely your path is wrong.