# Are os.system() and subprocess.call() any different?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there a functional difference between the following two methods?

```
os.system("echo $HOME")
subprocess.call("echo $HOME")
```

This is a similar question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13334634/the-difference-between-os-system-and-subprocess-calls), but that question really focuses more on `subprocess.Popen()`.

Comment: Yes. And you should basically always use `subprocess`. If you want a more complete answer, you need to first read the docs, and then tell us what parts you don't understand.

Comment: Side-note: Both of them are completely pointless, since they're basically equivalent to `print(os.environ["HOME"])`.

Comment: Also see https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system (in this case, of course, "Calling the program through the shell is usually not required" does not apply…)

Comment: If you're going to ask a question similar to others, please be more explicit/specific in the question about *exactly* what aspect of your problem isn't addressed elsewhere ("From question X, I understand A, but this still doesn't answer B").

Comment: @ShadowRanger It's just sample code. Side-note: I guess using `subprocess` is pointless by the same logic, because you could just type whatever you need on the shell.

Comment: @abarnert Please don't assume I didn't read the docs.  The [documentation on os.system](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) is clear as mud unless you are intimately familiar with native C - we cannot all be so fortunate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running python (cpython) on windows the `<built-in function system>` [os.system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) will execute under the curtains [_wsystem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz.aspx) while if you're using a non-windows os, it'll use [system](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html).

While subprocess.call will use [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) on windows and [_posixsubprocess.fork_exec](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/subprocess.py#L1423) in posix-based operating-systems.

The above points should answer your questions about the main differences (structurally)... That said, I'd suggest you follow the most important advice from the [os.system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) docs, which is:

> The subprocess module provides more powerful facilities for spawning
>   new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is
>   preferable to using this function. See the Replacing Older Functions
>   with the subprocess Module section in the subprocess documentation for
>   some helpful recipes.

Comment: Thank you @BPL - this is a much better answer than ones from the linked questions.