# python run external program and continue its execution indepentently

Tags: python, cross-platform, subprocess

How can i run an external program, let's say "Firefox", from my python script and make sure that its process will remain alive after the termination of my python script? I want to make it crossplatform if it's doable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204017/how-do-i-execute-a-program-from-python-os-system-fails-due-to-spaces-in-path

Comment: @jonjohnson: How does that answer this question, or even related to it? The question there is about a quoting problem with `os.system`, and the answer is to use `subprocess.call`, which will block until the child process finishes…

Comment: related: [Popen waiting for child process even when the immediate child has terminated](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13243807/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no cross-platform way to do this with just the stdlib. However, if you write code for POSIX and for Windows, that's usually good enough, right?

On Windows, you want to pass a [`creationflags`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) argument. Read the docs (both there and [at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684863%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) and decide whether you want a console-detached process, a new-console process, or a new-process-group process, then use the appropriate flag. You may also want to set some of the flags in `startupinfo`; again, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will tell you what they mean.

On POSIX, if you just want the simplest behavior, and you're using 3.2+, you want to pass `start_new_session=True`. In earlier Python versions, or for other cases, you want to pass a `preexec_fn` that allows you to do whatever daemonization you want. That could be as little as `os.setsid()` (what `start_new_session` does), or a whole lot more. See [PEP 3143 -- Standard daemon process library](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143/) for a discussion of all of the different things you might want to do here.

So, the simplest version is:

```
def launch_in_background(args):
    try:
        subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP
    except AttributeError:
        # not Windows, so assume POSIX; if not, we'll get a usable exception
        p = subprocess.Popen(args, start_new_session=True)
    else:
        # Windows
        p = subprocess.Popen(args, creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP)
```

---

If you're willing to go outside the stdlib, there are dozens of "shell-type functionality" libraries out there, many of which have some kind of "detach" functionality. Just search [`shell`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=shell&submit=search), [`cli`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=cli&submit=search), or [`subprocess`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=subprocess&submit=search) at PyPI and find the one you like best.