# Blocking and Non Blocking subprocess calls

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm completely confused between `subprocess.call()` , `subprocess.Popen()`, `subprocess.check_call()`.

Which is blocking and which is not ?

What I mean to say is if I use `subprocess.Popen()` whether the parent process waits for the child process to `return`/`exit` before it keep on its execution.

How does `shell=True` affect these calls?

Comment: did you try `subprocess.call([cmd,params,&])`?

Comment: @CharlieParker the `&` would have to be in quotation marks, and the `params` would have to be separate elements of the list, and it would have to use `shell=True`, and actually it should actually use a string instead of a pre-parsed list. It does work, but it's a hack.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

`Popen` is nonblocking. `call` and `check_call` are blocking.
You can make the `Popen` instance block by calling its `wait` or `communicate` method.

If you look in [the source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/005d0678f93c/Lib/subprocess.py#l527), you'll see `call` calls `Popen(...).wait()`, which is why it is blocking. 
`check_call` calls `call`, which is why it blocks as well.

Strictly speaking, `shell=True` is orthogonal to the issue of blocking. However, `shell=True` causes Python to exec a shell and then run the command in the shell. If you use a blocking call, the call will return when the *shell* finishes. Since the shell may spawn a subprocess to run the command, the shell may finish before the spawned subprocess. For example,

```
import subprocess
import time

proc = subprocess.Popen('ls -lRa /', shell=True)
time.sleep(3)
proc.terminate()
proc.wait()
```

Here two processes are spawned: Popen spawns one subprocess running the shell. The shell in turn spawns a subprocess running `ls`.  `proc.terminate()` kills the shell, but the subprocess running `ls` remains. (That is manifested by copious output, even after the python script has ended. Be prepared to kill the `ls` with `pkill ls`.)

Comment: [`start_new_session=True` or its analogs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13256908/4279) enables terminating the whole process tree at once. See [How to terminate a python subprocess launched with shell=True](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4789837/4279)

Comment: Thank you your answer helped me a lot.  P.S. `proc = subprocess.Popen(['/run_python.py', '-n', '10'], shell=True)` is different from that `proc = subprocess.Popen("run_python.py -n 10", shell=True)`  Only the last one works if the command is built on top of a python script.

Comment: @dotslash: `shell=True` can be a [security hazard](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) if the command comes from user input. So it is better to use `shell=False` if possible. With `shell=False`, supply the command and its arguments in a list: `proc = subprocess.Popen(['/run_python.py', '-n', '10'], shell=False)`.

Comment: @unutbu so `proc = subprocess.Popen(['/run_python.py', '-n', '10'], shell=False)` is this a blocking process? I `run_python.py` run at background which may last for 1 hour.

Comment: @dotslash: `Popen` is always non-blocking. It is calling `wait` or `communicate` which blocks.

Comment: But if I don't use `wait` my command [never executes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38012773/pygtk-progressbar-to-display-something-before-subprocess-starts)..?

Comment: I don't see this behaviour on Windows 10 with Python 3. I am running from VSCode's integrated console. I also tried on the default terminal. All child processes are killed!

Comment: what is wrong with using  `subprocess.call([cmd,params,&])`? i.e. adding the standard `&`?

Comment: so if i would like to use `shell=True` and i would like it to block the execution until the inner process of the shell ends, how could i do it?

Comment: @YuvalZilber simply *don't* include `&` in the shelled command. If the underlying process isn't backgrounded, the shell process will block on it, and `subprocess.call` in Python will block on the shell process.

Comment: The last example does not make sense. The shell process terminates immediately, as evidenced by the fact that the subsequent Python code runs immediately. The `proc.terminate` etc. is superfluous. An easier way to test, for people with Git installed, is `subprocess.call('gitk', shell=True)` at the REPL; the REPL will hang until the Gitk window is dismissed, because Python is blocking on the shell, and the shell is blocking on Gitk. However, with `subprocess.call('gitk &', shell=True)`, the repl will not hang, because the shell does not block on Gitk, because the Gitk process was backgrounded.