# How to run in python subprocess without blocking parent process?

Tags: python, django, multithreading, sockets, subprocess

I know the questions is similar to: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071866/non-blocking-subprocess-call), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21936597/blocking-and-non-blocking-subprocess-calls)  but answers for these questions didn't solve my problem.

*Workflow in nutshell:*

1.Web application sends request to backend. (written in django)

2.Backend starts *worker* process, to do some job by calling:

```
run_command = [sys.executable, my_python_worker, flags]
logger.debug('Created os update process "%s" ', run_command)
subprocess.Popen(run_command)
```

and in return parent process sends *http 200* to web application:

```
logger.debug('Sending response http 200')
return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

3.Progress of subprocess work is monitored by web application, by using backend api.

*The problem:*

Worker was implemented as a separate python script. To run *worker* I used `Popen` object from python [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) library. 
The subprocess has successfully started, I was able observe the progress of it work in second shell console. The execution of parent process in backend is also ongoing. I was able to see the log `Sending response http 200` but the response *http 200* to web application has never came.
However at the moment when subprocess ends (because it has ended it work , or I kill it from shell) the missing *http 200* response is immediately received by web application.

*The question:*

As in the title, how to run subprocess in python, that it will not block sending http response by parent process ?

Comment: it is probably an overkill in your case but in general you could use something like http://www.celeryproject.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the documentation of [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) library I found the flag: `close_fds`.
According to documentation:

> If close_fds is true, all file descriptors except 0, 1 and 2 will be closed before the child process is executed. (Unix only). Or, on Windows, if close_fds is true then no handles will be inherited by the child process. Note that on Windows, you cannot set close_fds to true and also redirect the standard handles by setting stdin, stdout or stderr.

I changed line in my code from:

```
subprocess.Popen(run_command)
```

to:

```
subprocess.Popen(run_command, close_fds=True)
```

and it solved the problem. It seems that subprocess has acquired and blocked socket used by parent process.

Comment: If you running a server process, then consider using `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` to run the child tasks.

Comment: And also be careful as subprocesses are attack-prone.