# How to validate that subprocess.Popen is non blocking

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, nonblocking

A couple of answers ([first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21936682/2373278), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16071877/2373278)) have mentioned that `subprocess.Popen` is a non blocking call.

What can be a simple example which can validate it or can be used to explain it to a beginner.

I tried the following code. It shows that "Finish" is printed before printing output of `ls -lrt` but as soon as I add `sleep 10` before `ls -lrt` in command, it waits for command to finish.

```
import logging
import os
import subprocess
import signal
import time

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class Utils(object):

    @staticmethod
    def run_command(cmnd, env=None, cwd=None, timeout=0):
        p = subprocess.Popen(cmnd, shell=True, stdin=None, bufsize=-1, env=env,
                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                             close_fds=True, cwd=cwd, preexec_fn=os.setsid)

        #stdout_val = p.communicate()[0]
        stdout_val = p.stdout.read()
        return p.returncode, stdout_val.strip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Start"
    print "Invoke command"
    status, output = Utils.run_command("ls -lrt")   # line - 10
    #status, output = Utils.run_command("sleep 10;ls -lrt") # line - 11
    for i in xrange(10):
        print "Finish"
    print status
    print output
```

EDIT 1: Replacing call p.communicate() with p.stdout.read() after suggestion.

Comment: `p.communicate` blocks which means that `Utils.run_command` will block until the command finishes.

Comment: @mgilson : Thanks for catching that. But if I replace `p.communicate()` with `p.stdout.read()` even then behavior is same.

Comment: @ViFI, of course it does, because `read()` blocks too (it doesn't return until it's able to get all the way to EOF).

Comment: ...by the way, if you're trying to teach things to beginners, please avoid showcasing bad practices such as use of `shell=True`. If you're creating a general-purpose utility function, it's better to do the safe and performant thing by default, and let your callers explicitly invoke a shell if they need one (as by using `["sh", "-c", "sleep 10; ls -lrt"]`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : and that's where a beginner's book ends :) Is there anything else I can do to make it non blocking ? Thanks.

Comment: @ViFI, well, sure, but what do you want to do instead of blocking? Do you want to read only one line (and block if there's not a line of content yet, but otherwise proceed)? Do you want to read the amount of content that's already-been written? Do you want some other random thing I haven't thought to propose? :)

Comment: actually, better to just point to a duplicative question, rather than draw out with details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Actually this code has to be used by a non blocking process. If this code is blocking it basically nullifies the "non blocking" nature of parent process.

Comment: In that case you should **really** be reading the linked question. Whatever other non-blocking code you're using will presumably already be using asyncio, or twisted, or another such option; you should be following its lead, not trying to do your own thing.

Comment: ...which is to say: If you're going to be called by other non-blocking code, then you need to play nice with its abstractions. That might mean you're obliged to be a coroutine rather than a regular function, or obliged to return a channel, or one of many other things. Details matter.

Comment: (...and moreover, this means you lied to us when you said that the purpose of this was to be a training piece demonstrating that the creation of a Popen object was a non-blocking operation; if you need to actually use it in a non-training role, that's a different question with a larger set of constraints, as referenced above).