# Python GUI using os.system to run python script cause main GUI "Not Responding"

Tags: python, performance, user-interface, lag

StackOverflow community. 
I am writing a python GUI to monitor another program's data in OSX environment and at one point I decide to click one button to open another python script that I wrote. It does work but it also causes a lag problem of the main GUI program as soon as I click the button. For the lag problem I mean the GUI window is "Not Responding" and I need to force quit. The method I use to run the new script is,

```
def create_html():
os.system('python realtime.py')
```

My program doesn't have the multiple class structure, just the simple canvas, and framework. I wonder if this is also the problem to cause my program running slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are using `os.system`, which is a blocking call. It will not return control to your main code until `python realtime.py` is done executing and returned.

You need to use a call that will not block the rest of your program, such as `subprocess.Popen`.

You can also see [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21936597/blocking-and-non-blocking-subprocess-calls) for further information

Comment: Is there a method to make the file that I want to subprocess.Popen be on top of the main GUI program?

Comment: Not easily. Usually `Popen` and the like are used to call command line programs that do not have a GUI. No easy built-in controls exist to do what you want, but you could do something more complicated with OS bindings to manipulate windows.