# Run a while-loop as subprocess in background

Tags: python, multithreading, terminal, subprocess, arguments

Unhappily my last post was marked as duplicate and my problem wasn't solved. So I've to phrase it a little bit different.

Below you can see my main-file(SP_Test.py) which calls another python script with an argument.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess

channels = input("")

subprocess.call(['python', '/Users/christian/pyth/term/helloworld.py', str(channels)])

print("Hello")
```

And here you can see my processing file which gets called by the main-file and should work in the background (The original file processes continuously audio inputs).

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

print("Hello World!")
print(sys.argv[1])

while(1):
    x=1
```

Now the problem is that I want to run this while-loop in the background while my main program (SP_Test.py) continues. So far it gets stuck in the loop and won't come back, so that it will never print "Hello".

I didn't find a solution in this forum what works for me. So plz help me. Thanks.

---

PS: Is it also possible to call the "helloworld.py" in a conda environment from the main-file?

Comment: Your last question _was_ a duplicate. You probably want to see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21936597/blocking-and-non-blocking-subprocess-calls?lq=1) to start you off, or you want to look into threading. I'm not sure I follow the narrative across the two questions

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess.call()` will wait until the command is completed, therefore blocking your program.
Instead you want to use `subprocess.Popen`, which will run the program in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are flushing the output from the buffer to the terminal. I think this is what you are looking for:

hello.py

```
import time
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print("hello",flush=True)
```

main.py

```
import subprocess
cmnd = ["python3","hello.py"]
p1 = subprocess.Popen(cmnd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in iter(p1.stdout.readline, ''):
    print(line)

p1.stdout.close()
```