# How do I run multiple commands with python subprocess( ) without waiting for the end of each command?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, terminal, subprocess, google-compute-engine

There are **two python scripts involved** in this task.

My current task requires me to run a long process(takes about a day or two per each, and this is the **first python script**) in each of 29 available regions on GCP's instances. In order to finish the task as quick as possible, I'm trying to run each process in each instance all at once after spinning off 29 VMs all at once.

As manually running the **first script** by SSH-ing in to each of the instance is cumbersome, I wrote a **python script(the second script**) that SSHs into each region's VM and runs the **first script** I mentioned above.

The issue with **the second script** that runs **first script** in different regions is that it doesn't start off to run the **first script** in second region's VM until it finishes running in the first region's VM, whereas I need the **second script** to run the **first script** in every region without waiting for the process started by **first script** to end.

I use subprocess() in the **second script** to run the **first script** in each VMs.

The following code is the **second script**:

```
for zone, instance in zipped_zone_instance:
    command = "gcloud compute ssh --zone " + zone + " " +  instance + " --project cloud-000000 --command"
    command_lst = command.split(" ")
    command_lst.append("python3 /home/first_script.py")
    subprocess.run(command_lst)
```

I need the subprocess.run(command_lst) to run for every 29 zones at once rather than it running for the second zone only after the first zone's process ends.

The following code is the **first script**:

```
for idx, bucket in enumerate(bucket_lst):

    start = time.time()
    sync_src = '/home/' + 'benchmark-' + var_
    subprocess.run(['gsutil', '-m', '-o', 'GSUtil:parallel_composite_upload_threshold=40M', 'rsync', '-r', sync_src, bucket])
    end = time.time() - start
    time_lst.append(end)
    tput_lst.append(tf_record_disk_usage / end)
```

What can I fix in the **second script** or the **first script** to achieve what I want??

Comment: `subprocess.run` is a blocking process.  Have you tried using `subprocess.Popen`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21936597/blocking-and-non-blocking-subprocess-calls, https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Switch out your `subprocess.run(command_lst)` with `Popen(command_lst, shell=True)` in each of your scripts and and loop through the command list like the example below to run the processes in parallel.

This is how you implement Popen to run processes in parallel using arbitrary commands for simplicity.

```
from subprocess import Popen

commands = ['ls -l', 'date', 'which python']

processes = [Popen(cmd, shell=True) for cmd in commands]
```