# python cannot kill process using process.terminate

Tags: python

I have a python code as following:

```
import threading
import time
import subprocess, os, sys, psutil, signal
from signal import SIGKILL

def processing():
    global p_2
    global subp_2
    .
    .
    .
    if condition1: #loop again
          threading.Timer(10,processing).start()
    if condition2:
          signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
          #signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)
          subp_2.terminate()   
          #os.kill(subp_2.pid, 0)
          #subp_2.kill()            
          print " Status p_2: ", p_2.status

def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    print('Exiting')
    sys.exit(0)

def function():
    global p_1
    global subp_1
    .
    .
    .
    if condition1: #loop again
          threading.Timer(5,function).start()

    if condition2:

          signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
          #signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)
          subp_1.terminate()   
          #os.kill(subp_1.pid, 0)
          #subp_1.kill()            
          print " Status p_1: ", p_1.status
          threading.Timer(10,processing).start()  
          subp_2 =  subprocess.Popen('./myScript2.sh %s %s' % (arg0, arg1), shell=True)
          p_2 = psutil.Process(subp_2.pid)

if __name__ == '__main__':
          global p_1
          global subp_1 
          .
          .
          .
          subp_1 = subprocess.Popen(["/.../myScript1.sh"],  shell=True)
          p_1 = psutil.Process(subp_1.pid)
          threading.Timer(5,function).start()
```

I could not kill the processe subp_1 and subp_2. Whatever I tried: .terminate(), .kill() or os.kill() I am still getting process status running. Could anyone tell me please what am I missing ? Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `shell=True`, first a subprocess is spawned which runs the shell. Then the shell spawns a subprocess which runs `myScript2.sh`. The subprocess running the shell can be terminated without terminating the `myScript2.sh` subprocess.

If you can avoid using `shell=True`, then that would be one way to avoid this problem. If using user input to form the command, `shell=True` should definitely be avoided, since it is a [security risk](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call).

On Unix, by default, the subprocess spawned by `subprocess.Popen` is *not* a [session leader](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18166/3330). When you send a signal to a session leader, it is propagated to all processes with the same session id. So to have the shell pass the `SIGTERM` to `myScript2.sh`, make the shell a session leader.

For Python versions < 3.2 on Unix, that can be done by having the shell process run `os.setsid()`:

```
import os
subp_2 =  subprocess.Popen('./myScript2.sh %s %s' % (arg0, arg1), 
                           shell=True, 
                           preexec_fn=os.setsid)

# To send SIGTERM to the process group:
os.killpg(subp_2.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

For Python versions >= 3.2 on Unix, pass `start_new_session=True` to `Popen`.

For Windows, see [J.F. Sebastian's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13256908/190597).

Comment: thanks, and how to terminate, or kill sub_p2 ? 
I've tried os.kill(subp_listenSlave.pid, 0) but the status is sleeping,  
If I use subp_2.terminate() and put time.sleep(0.5) after, the status is zombie

Comment: Whenever I define in the main function signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler) I got: AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'SIGTERM'

Comment: This is saying that somewhere in the main function you are redefining `signal` to equal a `bool`.

Comment: Note also that using `signal.signal` is [not the best way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1114567/190597) to implement timeouts. Consider using [jcollado's `Command` class](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4825933/190597) instead.

Comment: yes I find the redefinition, my bad.
However I am still getting zombie status after executing exactly what you told me to do.

Comment: Please post a runnable version of your program which demonstrates the problem.