# Do NOT terminate python subprocess when script ends

Tags: python, subprocess

I've seen a *ton* of questions for the opposite of this which I find odd because I can't keep my subprocess from closing but is there a way to call subprocess.Popen and make sure that it's process stays running after the calling python script exits?

My code is as follows:

```
dname = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
script = '{}/visualizerUI.py'.format(dname)
self.proc = subprocess.Popen(['python', script, str(width), str(height), str(pixelSize)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

This opens the process just fine, but when I close out of my script (either because it completes or with Ctrl+C) it also closes the visualizerUI.py subprocess, but I want it to stay open. Or at least have the option.

What am I missing?

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13256908/2073595) work for you?

Comment: Have you tried forking your script to the background?

Comment: huh?? Don't think Windows has forking

Answer (score 2):

Remove **stdout=subprocess.PIPE** and add **shell=True** so that it gets spawned in a subshell that can be detached.

Comment: If I add shell=True it doesn't work on Mac. And it does the samething without the stdout part.

Comment: By doesn't work on Mac I mean that the window doesn't come up (visualizerUI.py runs a Tkinter app)

Comment: It still does the same thing with shell=True

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use:

```
import os
os.system("start python %s %s %s %s" % (script, str(width), str(height), str(pixelSize)))
```

To start your new python script in a new process with a new console.

Edit: just saw that you are working on a Mac, so yeah I doubt this will work for you.

How about:

```
import os
import platform

operating_system = platform.system().lower()
if "windows" in operating_system:
    exe_string = "start python"
elif "darwin" in operating_system:
    exe_string = "open python"
else:
    exe_string = "python"
os.system("%s %s %s %s %s" % (exe_string, script, str(width),
          str(height), str(pixelSize))))
```

Comment: I'm targeting Mac, Windows AND Linux... so it needs to work everywhere.

Comment: apparently on a Mac the equivalent command is "open", but I don't have one nearby to test.

Comment: I'm doing this in a FastAPI program, launched using uvicorn. As soon as the program terminates, the process I launched does too. even with nohup ... & put on it.