# Opening .exe files without the program closing after executing of python script stopped

Tags: python, python-3.x, scripting, subprocess

In the code below I am trying to create certain groups of apps I can start through typing a certain number in the input field. The problem I am facing is that the apps (in this case Firefox) are closing after the python script is finished with executing. Is there a way to start an .exe file without the program exiting together with the script?

```
import subprocess

app_group_choice = int(input('Enter app group to open: '))

def Apps_school():
    subprocess.call(r"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe")
    print("Ok")

if app_group_choice == 1:
    Apps_school()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do NOT terminate python subprocess when script ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25127561/do-not-terminate-python-subprocess-when-script-ends)

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce the same error. What OS are you using? When I ran the provided code, Firefox remained open after the program ended.

However, it appears that `subprocess.Popen()` might be the right function to use for this application. It opens the app in a new process and then continues with the code but the lifetime of the app (e.g. Firefox) is not dependent on the script that called it. (https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so apparently I had this problem only when I was running my python script from the terminal inside VSCode which maybe had parameters that led to Firefox not staying open. When I ran it straight from cmd or by double clicking It worked perfectly fine.