# How to keep a subprocess running after python closes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I want to keep applications that I run using the subprocess library to keep running even after python closes. The following code opens notepad for a short while and then the program closes.

```py
from subprocess import Popen
from time import sleep
Popen('start notepad', shell=True)
sleep(1)
```

I tried the solutions from the following posts, but none of them work.
[Do NOT terminate python subprocess when script ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25127561/do-not-terminate-python-subprocess-when-script-ends)
[Popen waiting for child process even when the immediate child has terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243807/popen-waiting-for-child-process-even-when-the-immediate-child-has-terminated)
`os.startfile("notepad")` also doesn't work

I am using Windows 10 and would prefer if no other terminal window opened.
How can I achieve this behavior?

Comment: On Windows only, there is also [`os.startfile()`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.startfile). That might be what you're looking for instead of `subprocess.Popen`.

Comment: @Chris It still closes afer a while. I also did exactly what the first answer said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25127561/do-not-terminate-python-subprocess-when-script-ends), could you explain where I am going wrong?

Comment: That information belongs in your question. Please [edit] it and add details about what you have already tried to show how this question is different from the marked duplicate.