# Python subprocess.popen() without waiting

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I'm using Python 3.4.2 on Windows. In script1.py I'm doing this:

```
myProc = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "script2.py", "argument"])
myProc.communicate()
```

it works and call script2.py . 
The problem is that in script2.py there is a infinite loop (there must be) and the script1.py is waiting for script2.py to finish. How can I tell to script1.py to just call script2.py and don't wait for the process to finish?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243807/popen-waiting-for-child-process-even-when-the-immediate-child-has-terminated

Comment: Unrelated: as  a more flexible alternative, you could import the script as a Python module instead (use `if __name__ =="__main__"`  guard in it, to avoid running the code on import) and call functions directly or using `threading`, `multiprocessing`, `concurrent.futures` if needed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just don't call `myProc.communicate()` if you don't want to wait. `subprocess.Popen` will start the process.

Comment: I can't believe it..sorry for the silly question, and thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

Call the script in another window.

```
myProc = subprocess.Popen(["start", sys.executable, "script2.py", "argument"])
myProc.communicate()
```

`start` is a windows shell function that runs a program separately, allowing the current one to continue its process. I haven't tested this as I've no access to a Windows OS, but The linux equivalent (`nohup`) works as required.

If you need fine control over what happens with script2.py, refer to the `multiprocessing` module [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).