# How to achieve Perl's exec function in Python?

Tags: python

Assume using Linux:

In Perl, the [`exec` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html) executes an external program and immediately exits itself, leaving the external program in same shell session.

A very close answer using Python is https://stackoverflow.com/a/13256908

However, the Python solution using `start_new_session=True` starts an external program using setsid method, that means that solution is suitable for making a daemon, not an interactive program.

Here is an simple example of using perl:

```
perl -e '$para=qq(-X --cmd ":vsp");exec "vim $para"'
```

After vim is started, the original Perl program has exited and the vim is still in the same shell session(vim is not sent to new session group).

How to get the same solution with Python.

Comment: Actually, `exec` simply replaces the program running in the existing process.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perl is just wrapping the [`exec*` system call functions](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) here. Python has the same wrappers, in the `os` module, see the [`os.exec*` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.execl):

> These functions all execute a new program, replacing the current process; they do not return. On Unix, the new executable is loaded into the current process, and will have the same process id as the caller.

To do the same in Python:

```
python -c 'import os; para="-X --cmd \":vsp\"".split(); os.execlp("vim", *para)'
```

`os.execlp` accepts an argument list and looks up the binary in `$PATH` from the first argument.

The `subprocess` module is only ever suitable for running processes *next* to the Python process, not to replace the Python process. On POSIX systems, the `subprocess` module uses the low-level `exec*` functions to implement it's functionality, where a *fork* of the Python process is then replaced with the command you wanted to run with `subprocess`.