# Background process that will kill the current process

Tags: python, bash

I'm writing a python script that may execute an external bash script. This bash script does something, and after it's done executing, it will kill the python process, and possibly restart the machine.

It is by design that the bash script would kill the python process and restart the machine, but I'm not sure whether it will still continue executing even if it's parent python process dies. Since the machine will restart after the bash script completes, I'm not interested with its output.

Will the bash script still continue running even after the parent python process dies?

Comment: Why don't you just try this experiment or search the internets?

Comment: How do you launch the bash script?

Comment: uselpa Using subprocess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use:

```
os.system('/path/to/script.sh &')
```

or

```
subprocess.call('/path/to/script.sh &', shell=True)
```

The process will keep going even if the python script dies.

If you are **always** going to reboot, let the OS kill the parent and you not worry about it.

Comment: By the way `subprocess` should be used instead of `os.system`.

Comment: I don't think it is necessary in this case, but I added it anyways.

Comment: Is there a way that doesn't use `shell=True`?

Comment: Basically no. Not with subprocess. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12341701/how-to-send-a-subprocess-to-the-background-without-using-shell-true

Comment: It seems that `os.execv` is the way to go in my case. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

yes. You can start a child process that can continue to run after the process that started it exited. [Here's how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13256908/4279) without using `shell=True` or `os.system()`.